# How can I accumulate my totals in a more functional manner?

Tags: scala

At the moment I have

```
val orders = new HashMap[Int, Int]
orders.put(36, 110)
orders.put(35, 90)
orders.put(34, 80)
orders.put(33, 60)
```

I would like to keep a running so that the end mapping appears as follows

```
36 -> 110
35 -> 200
34 -> 280
33 -> 340
```

At the moment I do this imperatively as follows

```
val keys = orders.keys.toList.sortBy(x => -x)
val accum = new HashMap[Int, Int]
accum.put(keys.head, orders(keys.head))
for (i <- 1 to keys.length - 1) {
  accum.put(keys(i), orders(keys(i)) + accum(keys(i-1)))
}
accum.foreach {
  x => println(x._1, x._2)
}
```

Is there a more functional way of doing this using mapping, folding etc? I would be able to do it with a straight List but the can't quite wrap my head around how to do this with HashMap

Edit: Ordering is important. The left column (36, 35, 34, 33) needs to be in descending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, here is a solution using the `inits` method:

```
 import scala.collection.mutable._

 // use a LinkedHashMap to keep the order
 val orders = new LinkedHashMap[Int, Int]
 orders.put(36, 110)
 orders.put(35, 90)
 orders.put(34, 80)
 orders.put(33, 60)


// create a list of init sequences with no empty element
orders.toSeq.inits.toList.dropRight(1).

  // > this returns
  // ArrayBuffer((36,110), (35,90), (34,80), (33,60)) 
  // ArrayBuffer((36,110), (35,90), (34,80)) 
  // ArrayBuffer((36,110), (35,90)) 
  // ArrayBuffer((36,110)) 

  // now take the last key of each sequence and sum the values of the sequence
  map(init => (init.last._1, init.map(_._2).sum)).reverse.toMap.mkString("\n")

  36 -> 110
  35 -> 200
  34 -> 280
  33 -> 340
```

Answer (score 6):

Since HashMaps aren't sorted, it's not so simple to do this directly, so convert to an ordered sequence first:

```
val elems = orders.toSeq.sortBy(-_._1)
             .scanLeft(0,0)((x, y) => (y._1, x._2 + y._2)).tail

  // ArrayBuffer((36,110), (35,200), (34,280), (33,340))
```

If you actually want to stick these in an ordered map with reverse ordering, rather than just print them out, you could do this:

```
val accum = collection.SortedMap(elems: _*)(
            new Ordering[Int] { def compare(x: Int, y: Int) = y compare x })

  // SortedMap[Int,Int] = Map(36 -> 110, 35 -> 200, 34 -> 280, 33 -> 340)
```

Comment: `Ordering.Int.reverse` would look slightly better than `new Ordering[Int] { def compare(x: Int, y: Int) = y compare x }`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
val orders = new HashMap[Int, Int]
orders.put(36, 110)
orders.put(35, 90)
orders.put(34, 80)
orders.put(33, 60)

val accum = new HashMap[Int, Int]

orders.toList.sortBy(-_._1).foldLeft(0){
    case (sum, (k, v)) => {
     accum.put(k, sum + v)
     sum + v
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing it wrong. Don't create a `Map` directly: create a sequence. In this case, a `ListBuffer` is probably the most appropriate, so that you can easily append elements to it. It also supports constant time `toList`, though that shouldn't matter here.

If you must use a functional approach, you can either prepend to a `List` and `reverse` it, or go the way of *iteratees*. I'm not comfortable enough with the latter to explain them, though.

Once you have your collection, you'll `scanLeft` it. Or, if you built a `List`, you could `scanRight` it instead of having to `reverse` it. After that, it is a simple matter of calling `toMap` on the result.

Roughly speaking:

```
var accum: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil
accum ::= 36 -> 110
accum ::= 35 -> 90
accum ::= 34 -> 80
accum ::= 33 -> 60

val orders = accum.scanRight(0 -> 0) {
  case ((k, v), (_, acc)) => (k, v + acc)
}.init.toMap
```

The `init` drops the seed. I could have avoided having to do that using `tail` and `head`, but that would require a check to see if `accum` is empty.

The `var` can be removed using either iteratees, or, perhaps, using the state monad at a higher level.

Comment: I was using a Map for insertion speed otherwise would have gone with List

Comment: @deltanovember adding to the head of an immutable list is likely faster than inserting in a Map. Think about how linked lists work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0
orders.toList.sortBy (-_._1).map (o =>
  {sum += o._2; (o._1 -> sum) }).toMap
```

Not very elegant, since it uses a var.